# Looking for word that with meaning to reexamine your own life and point of view objectively.

Tags: single-word-requests

Word for stepping back mentally and examine objectively your own behavior and values.

Comment: A sample sentence is required!  The research you have done is helpful in any question.

Answer (score 2):

> **Self Awareness**
>    [pathwaytohappiness](https://www.pathwaytohappiness.com/self-awareness.htm)   Is having a clear perception of your personality, including strengths, weaknesses, thoughts, beliefs, motivation, and emotions. Self Awareness allows you to understand other people, how they perceive you, your attitude and your responses to them in the moment.

or

> **Introspection**
>   [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection)   Is the examination of one's own conscious thoughts and feelings.[1](https://www.pathwaytohappiness.com/self-awareness.htm) In psychology, the process of introspection relies exclusively on observation of one's mental state, while in a spiritual context it may refer to the examination of one's soul. Introspection is closely related to human self-reflection and is contrasted with external observation.
>   Introspection generally provides a privileged access to our own mental states,[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection) not mediated by other sources of knowledge, so that individual experience of the mind is unique.

Answer (score 0):

According to OED, [autoanalysis](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/autoanalysis) dates back to the late 19th century, around the time when psychoanalysis was being developed as a profession.